# Inject Imports with Vite

Tags: javascript, svelte, vite, rollupjs, esbuild

I am using Vite as my build tool for a svelte frontend application.

Some of the libraries I am using are Node.js modules that require the Buffer module. To provide the Buffer functionality, I am using the excellent [buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer) module. I need the buffer functionality for my application to work, so I can't just get away with a simple polyfill. My Vite config looks like this:

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [inject({ Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'] })]
    }
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      define: { global: 'globalThis' },
      plugins: [NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({ process: true })]
    }
  },
  plugins: [svelte({
    experimental: { prebundleSvelteLibraries: true },
    preprocess: [sveltePreprocess({ typescript: true }), optimizeImports()]
  })]
});
```

The problem is that while my production build works (the Buffer functionality is injected by the `inject` plugin in the `rollupOptions`), the development build does not use rollup, so it fails. How can I get both the production and development builds to inject the Buffer library where it's needed?

Comment: _"I can't just get away with a simple polyfill"_ why?

Comment: its an open bug (2 years now) that polyfills don't work correctly in vite.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why polyfill can't solve your problem.

Try put this piece of code at the very beginning of your entry JS file (`src/index.js` probably), just to ensure it execute **before** `Buffer` global is ever used.

```js
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
globalThis.Buffer = Buffer; // <-- polyfill
```